# Logistic Growth- Finding a harvesting percentage to cause extinction

Tags: recurrence-relations, mathematical-modeling

The Logistic growth equation with Percentage Harvesting is given by the following difference equation: $n(t+1)−n(t)=((−/)()+)*()−*()$
where $=1,000,000$ salmon, $=0.2311$, $(0)=900,000$ salmon, $=Percentage Harvested$, $=$.

What is the smallest percentage harvesting  that will cause extinction?

So am I right to think that the way to find the smallest percentage value of H that will cause an extinction would be for $*()>((−/)()+)*()$?

I think this would mean that every year the population is in decline so rearranging that inequality and solving for H would be the answer for the smallest H that would cause an extinction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation $*()>((−/)()+)*()$ is correct.
This will give you $>((−/)()+)$ and since $n(t)=0$ we get $H>b$
So $b$ is the smallest percentage harvesting $$ that will cause extinction